# Sub-folders of a Static Website on S3 and Route 53

Tags: web, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I recently started setting up a simple static website on AWS using S3 and Route 53. There are a number of tutorials for doing the basic parts, and there isn't that much complexity anyway. I'm able to view the main page (`index.html`) just fine; I just point the browser to `mypage.com` and I'm in business. However, I want to have a little bit of nested structure.

In my mypage.com aws bucket, I have a folder, mypage.com/music. Entering that url in the browser results in:

```
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
```

When what I'd expect is a simple folder view of the contents of that directory. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 doesn't generate folder views of what's in a bucket (except of course in the AWS console, but the directory listing shown there is not rendered by S3 -- it's rendered by the AWS console).

The `NoSuchKey` error refers to the fact that there is no object at `music/index.html`.

You would need to render your own directory listing as a static HTML file and save it as `music/index.html` or use the S3 SDK in a CloudFront/Lambda@Edge function to fetch the listing from the service and render a response.